# How to change the height of multiple iframes inside div using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have multiple iframes inside a div.The content of each iframe is different, therefore the height varies for each iframe.

```
<div id="multipleIframe">
    <iframe></iframe>
    <iframe></iframe>
    <iframe></iframe>
    <iframe></iframe>
</div>
```

I am using content carousel to switch between one iframe to other.

Initially what happens is that the content carousel animates automatically switching between each iframes. And then lands at the first iframe. Then the user can use the carousel navigation to switch between iframes.

I am manipulating the height of the iframe as below:

```
$("#multipleIframe iframe").each(function() {
    var heightIframe;
    heightIframe = $("iframe").contents().height();
    $("iframe").css({
        "height": heightIframe
    });
});
```

This works only for first iframe and the position of the remaining iframes is based on the first one, which is already calculated. Hence making the content truncated.

I want it to work during animation and when the user is trying to switch between iframes using navigation.

Does any one has solution to this problem?

Comment: It depends on How and When you are loading `<iFrame>` and the `Content` in it. Your jQuery Code will be Executed when Page is Loaded, and if you are adding Content after page loading on Remaining `<iFrame>` than it would not affect. But You can call a Function which changes Height of `<iFrame>` while you are adding content to it.

Comment: So, all the iframes should have same height?

Comment: So how do we do that?

Comment: No height of the iframe should be to its own height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work for you. The only case in which it may not work is when your code executes even before all iframes are loaded. In that case maybe the code finds only the first iframe and set it's height. Either, set a timer on the function and execute it after certain time interval. Here is the demo which shows this method:

http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/716/

Change it to:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $("#multipleIframe iframe").each(function () {
        var heightIframe;
        heightIframe = $(this).contents().height();
        console.log(heightIframe);
        $(this).css({
            "height": heightIframe + "px"
        });
    })
}, 3000);
```

Comment: @Archana Use a timer as mentioned in the answer